Is Instant Reload the only way to avoid provoking an attack of opportunity while reloading a projectile weapon?
For projectile weapons that cannot be reloaded as a free action, reloading provokes an attack of opportunity. Even the Rapid Reload feat notes that reloading still provokes an attack of opportunity—even for those crossbows the feat has reduced to reloading as a free action.
The epic feat Instant Reload does remove the attack of opportunity, but it’s an epic feat. It also bizarrely requires Quick Draw for some reason?
I can’t find any other feats that address this, or any classes. Even the ghostly reload spell doesn’t seem to cover it (though that might be an oversight as it goes unmentioned and it’s not clear how or why you would provoke). A few things nix the attack of opportunity for ranged attacks themselves, but nothing seems to for reloading.
So are there any other options that eliminates that provoking from reloading? Anything published by Wizards of the Coast, or from Dragon or Dungeon magazines, are acceptable, but I’m not looking for shenanigans, I want something that just says “reloading does not provoke an attack of opportunity for you” or similar (as Instant Reload does).

The feat Xaniqos School (Drow of the Underdark 57) possesses the phenomenally difficult prerequisites of Dexterity 13 or higher; the feats Dodge (Player's Handbook 93), Mobility (98), Point Blank Shot (ibid.), and Shot on the Run (100); and a base attack bonus +6. In addition to providing an ersatz skirmish-like +1d6 points of damage with a crossbow, the feat's benefit says that "reloading your crossbow does not provoke attacks of opportunity."

Painful, but at least it exists.

I went so far as to import into my last 3.5 campaign the Pathfinder feat Crossbow Mastery for the player who wanted a PC crossbowman. Instant Reload and Xaniqos School are, so far as I'm aware, the only feats in official and semiofficial 3.5 that do precisely this.
